# Java code compilation using JavaCompiler API and compilation errors handling

Tags: java, compilation

I have the following Java code that compiles the given Java code using the `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` API:

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
ByteArrayOutputStream err = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
compiler.run(new FileInputStream("Test.java"), 
    new FileOutputStream("Test.class"), 
    err, 
    "Test.java"); // Test.java contains the code of a simple Java class
String compilationErrors = err.toString();
```

In the above code, all compilation errors are returned as one `String` instance.

Is there a way to get compilation errors parsed i.d. get the file name, line number, cause of the error and line of code or do I have to do the parsing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my understanding of [`JavaCompiler.getTask(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html#getTask%28java.io.Writer,%20javax.tools.JavaFileManager,%20javax.tools.DiagnosticListener,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable%29) I'd suggest adding a [`DiagnosticListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/DiagnosticListener.html).  It seems to provide all the details needed.

---

This is the code I have been looking for:

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = 
    new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();         
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.
    getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);

Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager.
    getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(new File("Test.java")));
CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, 
    null, null, compilationUnits);

task.call();

for(Diagnostic<?> error : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()) {
    // 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be exactly what I am looking for. Will give it a try.